# Subspaces and their orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, B$ be subspaces. I want to show the following: $A \subseteq B \implies B^{\perp} \subseteq A^{\perp}$

Is the following a legitimate proof?

If $x \in A$, then $x \in B$ since $A \subseteq B$. Assume $x$ is not the zero vector. Then because $x \in A$, it must be the case that $x \notin A^{\perp}$. Similarly because $x \in B$ that means $x \notin B^{\perp}$. So we have shown that $x \notin A^{\perp} \implies x \notin B^{\perp}$.

Now by the contrapositive, we see that $x \in B^{\perp} \implies x \in A^{\perp}$. So $B^{\perp} \subseteq A^{\perp}$

Comment: Your argument is __not__ correct! $x \not\in A$ do not imply that $x \in A^\perp$.

Comment: @kjetil: I don't see where that's asserted in the question.

Comment: It seems tyo be there implicitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not generally true that $x\in A$ implies $x\notin A^\perp$, for instance in $\mathbb F_2^n$.

The proof is simpler than that and doesn't rely on any specifics of orthogonal complements. Since the orthogonal complement of $B$ is the set of all vectors that are orthogonal to all vectors in $B$, if we remove some elements from $B$ we've just made the requirement less stringent, so we can't have excluded any vectors from the orthogonal complement that were in it before; thus the orthogonal complement of a subset must be a superset of the orthogonal complement.

Comment: Thank you for the nice intuitive argument. Also what is $\mathbb{F}^n_2$

Comment: @Student: $\mathbb F_2$ is the [field with two elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF%282%29), the smallest [finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field), and $\mathbb F_2^n$ is the $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_2$ of $n$-tuples with elements in $\mathbb F_2$. I suspect that you were only thinking of vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ or perhaps $\mathbb C$, but since your conclusion holds in all vector spaces equipped with a bilinear form, over arbitrary fields, the proof should ideally work for all fields and not rely on specifics of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$.

Comment: But if my proof was for just $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ would it be ok?

Comment: @Student: No, it wouldn't. You assume that $x\in A$ and then try to derive an implication with premise $x\notin A^\perp$. But that implication has to hold for all $x\notin A^\perp$, not just for $x\in A$, so you can't prove it starting from $x\in A$. (The reason I mentioned $\mathbb R$ is just that $(x\ne0\land x\in A)\Rightarrow x\notin A^\perp$ does hold in $\mathbb R^n$.)

Comment: I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not.

If you want to prove about sets that $X\subseteq Y$, then it's usually going as:

1. suppose we are given $x\in X$
2. Then try to prove $x$ satisfies the criterium for $Y$ (i.e. $x\in Y$).

Now:
suppose we are given $u\in B^\perp$ (what does it mean? $u$ is orthogonal to the whole $B$), then conclude that $u\in A^\perp$, of course, using the hypothesis $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler argument is this:

Suppose $x \not\in A^{\perp}$, then $\exists$ $a \in A$ such that we have that $x \cdot a \neq 0 $, but since $a \in B$ (since $A \subseteq B$), it follows that $x \not\in B^{\perp}$ (because being in $B^{\perp}$ requires you to be orthogonal to everything in $B$). And now by contrapositive you're done.